# Removing a div in index.html using a condition from an element in another html file

Tags: javascript

I created a javascript to fetch the text in message.html, "I love food", and puts it in "box1" for display. Now, I want to remove the entire div element when there is no verbiage, "I love food". Just to test it out, I created a javascript to remove the box1, but I have no idea how to write a condition when message.html has no verbiage, remove the entire div, else do not execute.

In index.html

`<div class="box1" id="alertbox"></div>` <-- I would like to completely remove this entire div when there is no verbiage in message.html

In message.html

`<div id="test1"><p>I love food</p></div>`<-- puts it in "box1"

In message.html

`<p></p>` No verbiage.

Javascript (condition added but not working)

`var removebox1 = document.getElementById("alertbox");`
`removebox1.remove();`

`var x = document.getElementsById("test1").innerText.length;`
`if (x > 0){ removebox1.remove(); } else{} }`

Comment: Hello, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and you should also know [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Been a while and edited :)

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: removed related to "can someone help me?"

Answer (score 1):

i took out the first "removebox1.remove();" because it seemed to be removing the box right after storing the reference in the variable. if its something you need then im not totally certain how it will affect this attempt. i also changed x to textContent for a more clear name, but this was just a personal thing.

```
var removebox1 = document.getElementById("alertbox");
var textContent = document.getElementById("test1").innerText.trim();

if (textContent.length === 0) {
    removebox1.remove();
}
```

i am unsure on this but i thought maybe instead of checking x > 0, you could then just check if the content is equal to zero since there would be nothing there. i hope this can help you with the issue you are having

Comment: thanks for your help.. seems like 'trim' breaks the code but the code i have keeps showing 0 so I'm going to ask a new questions diffferntly and remove this today. but appreciate for your help!